# Matlab reshape horizontal cat

Tags: arrays, matlab

Hi I want to reshape a matrix but the reshape command doesn't order the elements the way I want it. 
I have matrix with elements:

```
A B
C D
E F
G H
I K
L M
```

and want to reshape it to:

```
A B E F I K
C D G H L M
```

So I know how many rows I want to have (in this case 2) and all "groups" of 2 rows should get appended horizontally. Can this be done without a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with two `reshape` and one `permute`. Let `n` denote the number of rows per group:

```
y = reshape(permute(reshape(x.',size(x,2),n,[]),[2 1 3]),n,[]);
```

Example with 3 columns, `n=2`:

```
>> x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12]
x =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
>> y = reshape(permute(reshape(x.',size(x,2),n,[]),[2 1 3]),n,[])
y =
     1     2     3     7     8     9
     4     5     6    10    11    12
```

Comment: Wow, that's horribly complicated but works! Thank you :)

Comment: @Stefan It won't look as complicated if you do the three steps separately: first `reshape(x.',size(x,2),n,[])` etc. That way you can see the intermediate results and get the logic behind it

Comment: Also this only works for square boxes. To generalize to any number of rows I think you have to change it to i.e:
numRows = 3;
`y = reshape(permute(reshape(x.',size(x,2),numRows,[]),[2 1 3]),numRows,[])`
Could you add that to the answer?

Comment: @Stefan I already did that generalization. Did you see my modified code and example?

Comment: yes I did the steps and it makes more sense. With the  reshaping into 3D etc. Still conceptually a bit complicated, hehe. But it's great.

Answer (score 1):

Cell array approach -

```
mat1 = rand(6,2) %// Input matrix
nrows = 3; %// Number of rows in the output

[m,n] = size(mat1);

%// Create a cell array each cell of which is a (nrows x n) block from the input
cell_array1 = mat2cell(mat1,nrows.*ones(1,m/nrows),n);  

%// Horizontally concatenate the double arrays obtained from each cell
out = horzcat(cell_array1{:})
```

Output on code run -

```
mat1 =
    0.5133    0.2916
    0.6188    0.6829
    0.5651    0.2413
    0.2083    0.7860
    0.8576    0.3032
    0.1489    0.4494
out =
    0.5133    0.2916    0.5651    0.2413    0.8576    0.3032
    0.6188    0.6829    0.2083    0.7860    0.1489    0.4494
```